# Java Array index out og bounds Exception when getting input in java

Tags: java, string, exception, input

I got Java `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when getting String input in Java. Please help me. This is my code: I edited my code to split using : it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at solution2.Solution.main(Solution.java:27)
"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.next();
    String strarr[] = str.split(",");
    String temp = strarr[0];
    String temparr[] = temp.split(".");
    String temp1 = strarr[1];
    String temparr1[] = temp.split(".");
    int x1 = Integer.parseInt(temparr[0]);
    int x2 = Integer.parseInt(temparr[1]);
    int y1 = Integer.parseInt(temparr1[0]);
    int y2 = Integer.parseInt(temparr1[1]);
    System.out.println(distance(x2,x1,y2,y1));

}

public static int distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){

    int xlen=x2-x1;
    int ylen=y2-y1;

    return (xlen+ylen)*10-(ylen*5);     

}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you should test the `length()` of your arrays before you index them?

Comment: (And it would be polite to indicate which line of your program is getting the error.)

Comment: Not only polite, but necessary, as there are lots of opportunities for said exception to be raised.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't have any validation, please, give us example what you want to type.

Comment: input:1.2,2.4 output:interger values such as 1,2,2,4 . format is very important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the dot character in the `String.split()` regex, otherwise *any* character will be matched:

```
String temparr[] = temp.split("\\.");
```

For `temparr1`, I think you meant to use `temp1`:

```
String temparr1[] = temp1.split("\\.");
```

If you are expecting double values you could use `Scanner.nextDouble()` instead.

Comment: can you tell me how to split using ":"

Comment: No need to escape `:`, just use `str.split(":")`

Comment: Changing the nature of the question does not help people who wish to read this in future. The answers now do not correspond to the question that is in place. I would say to put back the original code in the question and post a new question. :)

Comment: Thank you for restoring the original Q.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you are assigning `temp.split()` to `temparr1` instead of `temp1.split()`?

Also, `split` takes in a regular expression as an argument, and as it happens, the regexp `.` matches just about anything. So, you should correct that.

I assume, from lack of anything disproving my guess, that you are parsing an input of format `1.2,3.4`, where 1,2,3, and 4 are arbitrary numbers.

Beside that, `Scanner.next` reads in the next **token**, meaning that it will read only "1" from "1.2,3.4". You have to use `Scanner.nextLine`.

Comment: can you tell me how to split using ":"